# Prevent Closure Compiler moving methods out of a class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to write a JavaScript support script for Roll20 and to minify and typecheck it using the Closure Compiler.

Roll20 has very primitive module support and simply catenates together all scripts that are run in one game. Because of this, their style guide states that use of the global namespace should be minimised. In order to do this, my main script runs:

```
class Pathfinder2Utilities {
   ... methods ...

   constructor() {
     ... adds a roll20 event handler to call methods on the constructed instance ...
   }
}
new Pathfinder2Utilities();
```

This means that only `Pathfinder2Utilities` is exposed to the global namespace, and the executing instance of the class is anonymous and takes up no namespace. However, when I attempt to minify this using Closure Compiler, it moves some of the methods out of the class and turns them into global functions with single-letter names. It also adds some similar functions of its own. Since these functions would then clash with any other compiled script this makes the script unsuitable to upload.

The work-around suggested on the Closure Compiler is to add references to the global functions as members of the `Pathfinder2Utilities` object. But this isn't viable in this case because the global functions will still exist to cause name clashes.

How can I tell Closure to preserve the structure of the `Pathfinder2Utilities` class?

Comment: I don't know Roll20, but shouldn't minification be done after the concatenation, on the whole bundle?

Comment: "*the executing instance of the class is anonymous*" - this sounds like a bad idea. A class constructor shouldn't do any execution on its own, it should only initialise an instance for later use. It sounds like your situation does not call for a `class` (which is meant to produce multiple instances), but simply for an IIFE where you can declare a few local functions and do whatever you want without exposing *anything* to the global namespace.

Comment: @Bergi It can't be minified after concatenation - the concatenation takes place at the server. Roll20 does talk about the "revealing module pattern" which "emulates a class", but it seemed unnecessary to emulate a class when ES6 actually has them.

Comment: No, the revealing module pattern does not emulate classes. It does emulate module scopes with a single export. And if you don't need any global variable (`Pathfinder2Utilities`) at all, because you don't call it from anywhere else, you don't need to *reveal* anything at all - just use a plain IIFE.

Comment: Try wrapping what you have now in a self executing `(function(){...})()` to protect your scope. Closure would probably just strip this away, so instead of adding it to your source file(s), add it to your Closure Compiler flags with --output_wrapper https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Flags-and-Options